# vuejs: dynamic path to images

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, imagesource

I try to build a simple list with photos, but i dont get it how to build the pathes dynamicly.

template

```
<ul class="thumbnail-list">
    <li class="thumbnail-list__item thumbnail" v-for="item in data">
        <img :src="src(item.cover)" alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

script

```
computed: {
    src(img) {
        return require(`./photos/${img}`);
    },
},
```

This results in *"This relative module was not found:"*

I tried it then with the @

```
return require(`@/photos/${img}`);
```

But then I get this message
  *Unexpected require(), Calls to require() should use string literals*

Finally I tried this

```
return require('@/photos/' + img);
return require('~@/photos/' + img);
```

But thiss also doesnt work, I get the errors

*Unexpected require(), Calls to require() should use string literals, Unexpected string concatenation*

My photos are located under the folder "src/photos/"

If I put in my template a hardcoded src it finds the image

```
<img src="~@/photos/1.jpg">
```

so what im doing wrong?? ;)

Comment: Have you tried ```require(`@/photos/${img}`); // eslint-disable-line```? This way you can check if it is the eslint errors

Comment: `return require("./photos/${img}");`.  Use double quotes instead of single

Comment: @Advaith when i use doubleqoutes than i alwasy get the error message "This relative module was not found:"

Comment: @Nora that works, so it must be some linting error from the 'airbnb-base', but i don't know exactly what the linter want from me ;) 

"Unexpected require(), Calls to require() should use string literals"